# How to ensure that paint bucket tool fills region with EXACT color in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have selected the paint bucket tool in Photoshop, with a carefully selected foreground color, a tolerance of 8, and "anti-alias" and "contiguous" boxes UNchecked.

However, Photoshop nonetheless paints over the desired region of the image with some sort of "gradient" fill - the fill color is not EXACTLY my foreground color choice.

How can I ensure that the paint bucket tool fills the region with the EXACT foreground color in Photoshop?

ADDENDUM:

Here are before-and-after screenshots:

Original image (two layers):

[image: Before fill]

After fill using paint bucket tool with tolerance of 8 (Note: I want to fill the regions to the right side of the arrow with a single foreground color):

[image: After fill]

Here is a screenshot after using "Edit -> Fill" (as suggested by an answer):

[image: Edit -> Fill]

Finally, here is the color I WANT to fill with (the foreground color):

[image: Fill color]

Comment: Is the blending mode of the paint bucket tool set correctly? Each painting tool has blending modes which can be set independently from layer blending modes.

Comment: How do I set the blending mode such that there is "no blend", i.e. that it simply paints over the image with the foreground color?

Comment: @DanNissenbaum Mode should be set to "Normal"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I need to fill a selection I usually use `Edit -> Fill...` (or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>).

I'm not sure why you're experiencing that, if you post a screenshot of the result that would be helpful

---

### Edit: A more precise way to achieve what you're trying to do...

I would use the Polygonal Lasso Tool instead of the Pant Bucket Tool. You'll get less noise and you'll have more control over the pixels you want to fill.

I'm assuming your file looks something like this since you said the triangle is on a separate layer:

[image: Step 0]

#### Step 1: Select the area you want to fill with the Polygonal Lasso tool

[image: Step 1]

*The Polygonal Lasso Tool is sometimes hidden under the Lasso Tool or the Magnetic Lasso Tool, click and hold the icon to select the correct one.*

#### Step 2: Create a new layer underneath the triangle layer

[image: Step 2]

#### Step 3: Fill your selection using `Edit -> Fill...`

[image: Step 3]

*Select `Color...` from the `Use` dropdown and select your fill color of choice*

#### Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If what you want to achieve is this:

[image]

Then this is what you should do:

1. Select the first layer (the layer with the gradient)
2. Make a rectangular selection of the area you want to color (around the arrow till the edge of the image)
3. Press the delete key or erase that area
4. While the area is still selected, fill the area with the color of your choice